# Why does container-type: inline-size seem to mess with stacking / overflow rules?

Tags: css, container-queries

Using `container-type: inline-size` seems to mess with stacking rules and overflow.  I'm trying to understand why that is, and if there are any ways to work around what's seemingly another limitation.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.overflowing {
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.following {
  container-type: inline-size; /* comment this line out and text starts overflowing */
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overflowing">
    <p>
    Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="following">

</div>
```

Result without `container-type: inline-size` applied to the "following" container:

[image]

Result with `container-type: inline-size` applied to the "following" container:

[image]

As can be seen in the images, the following section seems to cover up the overflowing text...exactly why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Do'h...

It's because `container-type` is a CSS property that forms a new stacking context.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context

Setting `position: relative` and `z-index` on `container` can do the trick...but this probably won't scale very well in enterprise contexts...

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  container-type: inline-size;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overflowing {
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.following {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:red;
  container-type: inline-size;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overflowing">
    <p>
    Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah... Ipsum lorem blah blah...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="following">

</div>
```

Comment: This is a super dumb behavior and you are right it does not scale if you have a bunch of containers all at the same hierarchical level in the DOM then you have to set the z-index for every single container in descending z-index order. I had a complex layout with no media queries and a single container query. Then I noticed my tooltips were below the following container. Some CSS specs are always so close to being perfect and one tiny thing makes it practically useless. Who do I petition to change it? w3c?